# Android client killing connection

Tags: android, client, iostream

OK so I'm making a simple pc-android server-client app with this code:

```
package org.smiley.doom;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

public static ImageView im;
public static Socket s;
public static boolean go;
public static TextView log;
Button send;
EditText tip;
InetAddress inet;
int rport;
String ip;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIP);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSEND);
    im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPIC);
    log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLog);

    s = null;
    in = null;
    out = null;

    send.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.bSEND:
            byte[] b;
            int len;
                try {
                    inet = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.2");
                    s = new Socket(inet, 4321);
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    log.setText("Client opened");
                    len = in.readInt();
                    b = new byte[len];
                    in.read(b);
                    log.setText(b.length);
                    out.writeBoolean(true);
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    s.close();
                    System.out.println("Client closed");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    log.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
                }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

But for some reason, when ran, it'll connect to the server then crash without changing my textview log at all, i know its not a problem with the server as i had nearly this exact same code running on a normal java project and it connected flawlessly.  The problem seems to be when it trys to set up the object output/input streams(because thats all that happens in between the log updating and the client requesting a connection) but i cant figure out why for the life of me

as always any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: heres my logcat

```
07-20 14:17:22.374: W/ResourceType(335): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000096ce
07-20 14:17:22.374: D/AndroidRuntime(335): Shutting down VM
07-20 14:17:22.374: W/dalvikvm(335): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
String resource ID #0x96ce
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
org.smiley.doom.ClientActivity.onClick(ClientActivity.java:65)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-20 14:17:22.385: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output with the stack trace. I have a feeling you're running into the NetworkOnMainThreadException since you're not performing your network i/o on a background Thread.

Comment: It couldn't be I'm running gingerbread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `ResourcesNotFoundException` because one of the resources you're referencing can't be resolved in your XML. First try cleaning your project in Eclipse. You can do this by going to "Project -> Clean" and make sure you clean the correct project. Finally, make sure that your `main.xml` layout file is accessible by the version of Android you're testing on. It's possible you have it in a qualified directory that is inaccessible by the device (such as a xlarge layout directory).

Here is the relevant error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
[ ... ]
at org.smiley.doom.ClientActivity.onClick(ClientActivity.java:65)
[ ... ]
```

Comment: You sir are a god, i tried cleaning my project before with no success and i checked to make sure that my androids sdk was the sdk i was developing on and it was.  But i never noticed the "ClientActivity.java:65" part of the logcat so i checked it out - turns out i was trying to set my log text view's text (a string) to the amount of bytes read (an integer) which is why the string resource was not found...

Comment: Ah yeah, that would do it. `String.valueOf(...)` is your friend there.